# How do I improve my index array without typing it all out

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

```js
SLink = [...Array(100).keys()].map(i => `SotiLink[${i}]`)
MCLink = [...Array(100).keys()].map(i => `<MCLink${i}>`)

SotiLink = SLink + MCLink;  

console.log(SotiLink)
```

As a newbie to js I have been trying to improve the current situation, which is as follows:

```
 SotiLink[0] = "<MCLink0>";
 SotiLink[1] = "<MCLink1>";
 SotiLink[2] = "<MCLink2>";
```

Now this works fine, it gets the job done.
But I thought something like this would be better:

```
SotiLink[...Array(100).keys()] = "<MCLink0>", "<MCLink1>", "<MCLink2>", "<MCLink3>", "<MCLink4>", "<MCLink5>", "<MCLink6>", "<MCLink7>", "<MCLink8>", "<MCLink9>", "<MCLink10>", "<MCLink11>", "<MCLink12>", "<MCLink13>", "<MCLink14>", "<MCLink15>", "<MCLink16>", "<MCLink17>", "<MCLink18>", "<MCLink19>", "<MCLink20>", "<MCLink21>", "<MCLink22>", "<MCLink23>", "<MCLink24>", "<MCLink25>", "<MCLink26>", "<MCLink27>", "<MCLink28>", "<MCLink29>", "<MCLink30>", "<MCLink31>", "<MCLink32>", "<MCLink33>", "<MCLink34>", "<MCLink35>", "<MCLink36>", "<MCLink37>", "<MCLink38>", "<MCLink39>", "<MCLink40>", "<MCLink41>", "<MCLink42>", "<MCLink43>", "<MCLink44>", "<MCLink45>", "<MCLink46>", "<MCLink47>", "<MCLink48>", "<MCLink49>", "<MCLink50>", "<MCLink51>", "<MCLink52>", "<MCLink53>", "<MCLink54>", "<MCLink55>", "<MCLink56>", "<MCLink57>", "<MCLink58>", "<MCLink59>", "<MCLink60>", "<MCLink61>", "<MCLink62>", "<MCLink63>", "<MCLink64>", "<MCLink65>", "<MCLink66>", "<MCLink67>", "<MCLink68>", "<MCLink69>", "<MCLink70>", "<MCLink71>", "<MCLink72>", "<MCLink73>", "<MCLink74>", "<MCLink75>", "<MCLink76>", "<MCLink77>", "<MCLink78>", "<MCLink79>", "<MCLink80>", "<MCLink81>", "<MCLink82>", "<MCLink83>", "<MCLink84>", "<MCLink85>", "<MCLink86>", "<MCLink87>", "<MCLink88>", "<MCLink89>", "<MCLink90>", "<MCLink91>", "<MCLink92>", "<MCLink93>", "<MCLink94>", "<MCLink95>", "<MCLink96>", "<MCLink97>", "<MCLink98>", "<MCLink99>";
```

Where instead of numbering the Sotilink 0-100 it would generate all the numbers.
Ideally I would like the same for MCLink, but so far I had no succes.
I tried to recreate it somewhat in the snippet but I had no succes there either...
Perhaps someone can point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there ;)

```js
SotiLink = [...Array(100).keys()].map(i => `<MCLink${i}>`)

console.log(SotiLink)
```

As a side note, I'm wondering how did you create that snippet in your question. Did you really type all 100 strings? :o

Comment: I really hope they either used a loop to create all those 100 links ... or at least used something like the excel auto complete.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt have to type all of that, because some of it was already present, but about 70 I had to write myself...

Thanks for the answer by the way, I think i'm alot closer.
Sadly the current way all the js is setup it looks for SotiLink[Index] so it does not recognize this out of the box.

I tried to match the answers (see my snippet) but i'd have to interval them or something to make that work, like 1 from SLink and one from MCLink...etc

Comment: @Weasley: I don't understand. Are you trying to generate some JS code dynamically? So that it literally contains `SotiLink[0] = "<MCLink0>";SotiLink[1]=` etc?